# Deducing general solution from roots of characteristic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider a linear differential equation with constant coefficients. Given the roots of the characteristic polynomial to be 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -5, 2±3i, 2±3i, 1±5i, what is the order and general solution when the forcing is 0? Also, what is the characteristic, degree, and multiplicity of the following forcings $te^{-2t}$, $e^t\sin(5t)$, and $5t^3$?

Is this the correct approach the question is a bit confusing?

Order: 12
$$y(t) = c_1 + c_2t+ c_3e^t + c_4te^t + c_5t^2e^t + c_6e^{-5t} + c_7e^{2t}\cos(3t) + c_8e^{2t}\sin(2t) + c_9te^{2t}\cos(3t) + c_{10}te^{2t}\sin(3t) + c_{11}e^t\cos(5t) + c_{12}e^t\sin(5t)$$
$$te^{-2t} \implies d = 1, \mu +iv = -2, m=0$$
$$e^t\sin(5t) \implies d=0, \mu +iv=5i, m=0$$ 
$$5t^3 \implies d=3, \mu+iv=0, m = 2$$

Comment: A linear differential equation